# Count then remove similar polygon features

Tags: gdal, polygon, ogr, duplicates

Is there a feature, preferably in OGR, that will remove duplicate polygons and add a count of duplicates to the remaining features attribute field?

Comment: It's not what you are looking for and maybe it won't work but in QGIS you might run the delete duplicate geometries tool to create a new layer, then do a join by spatial location summary to the new with the original using the equal geometries and counts options.

Comment: Another workaround that requires unique area fields in QGIS is to use the count (1, "Area field") to populate a field, then run the delete duplicate geometries tool.

Comment: Can you explain the count(1, "Area Field") reference in your last lost? 
I don't understand where youare expecting the final count to result in anything but the original field of '1'

Comment: An area field, e.g. acres, is usually unique if a real number given the number of decimal places, so if two polygons share the same acres they are likely duplicates.  It's no guarantee and the extra decimal places may cause it to miss almost duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I was essentially trying to build a cumulative viewshed from multiple points, and found a plugin to do it.